# Using `xcodebuild` to do a command line builds for Catalyst/UIKit for Mac?

Tags: xcodebuild, mac-catalyst

I cannot see this documented anywhere — has anyine figured our how to use xcodebuild to build a propject for UIKIt for Mac (i.e. Catalyst)?

You can specify "-sdk iphoneos" vs "-sdk iphonesimulator" to toggle between those two targets, but "-sdk uikitformac" does not seem to work ("SDK not found"), despite Xcode itself using that nomenclature (e.g., it builds to a "Debug-uikitformac" folder, etc). i also tried different SDK values that might have made sense (such as "-sdk macabi"), but no avail.

Suggestions?

Comment: Uses`-sdk macosx` and append `SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST=YES` to the `xcodebuild` command

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```sh
xcodebuild -configuration "Debug" ARCHS="x86_64h" \
  -destination 'platform=macOS,variant=Mac Catalyst' \
  -project "MyApp.xcodeproj"
```

(note the extra 'h' on the architecture)

Answer (score 21):

Add script file to your projects folder:

```sh
SCHEME=TestFramework \
ARCHS=~/Documents/Archives \
```

`SCHEME` is the name of build scheme in Xcode.

Lets build macCatalyst archive:

```sh
#----- Make macCatalyst archive
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme $SCHEME \
-archivePath $ARCHS/macCatalyst.xcarchive \
-sdk macosx \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST=YES
```

Also you can add other platforms like iOS device or Simulator:

```sh
#----- Make iOS Simulator archive
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme $SCHEME \
-archivePath $ARCHS/simulator.xcarchive \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

#----- Make iOS device archive
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme $SCHEME \
-archivePath $ARCHS/iosdevice.xcarchive \
-sdk iphoneos \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

To include everything in XCFramework use:

```sh
#----- Make XCFramework
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework $ARCHS/simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/$SCHEME.framework \
-framework $ARCHS/iosdevice.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/$SCHEME.framework \
-framework $ARCHS/macCatalyst.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/$SCHEME.framework \
-output ~/Documents/$SCHEME.xcframework
```

After running you will find your XCFramework in your Documents folder.

Comment: This is the best way to build xcframeworks for macCatalyst.

Comment: `SCHEME is the name of build scheme in Xcode.` What if I want to make a third party framework into an xcframework? I cannot use `SCHEME` in that case since it isn't actually a scheme in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I used this to build a XCFramework that includes the Mac Catalyst framework

[XCFramework and Mac Catalyst](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120542)

Comment: If you can you should provide the core details in your answer along with a link

Comment: `-destination 'platform=macOS,arch=x86_64,variant=Mac Catalyst'` thanx! I'll try that and report back!